# Flutter how to handle state for row of checkboxes

Tags: flutter, state

New to Flutter, so I hope I'm using the right terms:

Inside my parent Stateful Widget, I'm creating a row of checkboxes.
When clicking on these checkboxes, I'd like to update the state of a list of of boolean values.
My question is:
How can I tell the "index" of the clicked checkbox?
Is there a better pattern for handling that?

```
class MyState extends State<Products> {

final List<bool> _data = [true, true, true];

Widget _buildCheckBoxes() {
    List<Widget> list = new List();
    Widget cb;
    for (bool val in _data) {
      cb = Checkbox(
            value: val,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                    // need to update _data[?]
                });
            },
        );
      list.add(cb);
    }

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: list
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: It'd probably be easier to use a `ListView.builder` so you can access the index of each child within the builder and then set the `scrollDirection` to `Axis.horizontal` as seen [here.](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list)

Comment: Yes - ListView.builder solves this by supplying an index, but it looks like an overkill.
Also - seems like a common task: to dynamically create a list (not a ListView) of widgets and binding them to a state / data...

Answer (score 3):

First: you can't update a final List `_data` because `final` means that the list is constant. Second although I prefer that u use listView because it is clearer, you can do the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return TestWidgetState();
  }

}
class TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget>{

  List<bool> _data = [true, true, true];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return _buildCheckBoxes();
  }

  Widget _buildCheckBoxes() {
    List<Widget> list = new List();
    Widget cb;

    for (int i=0;i<_data.length;i++) {
      cb = Checkbox(
        value: _data[i],
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            // need to update _data[?]
            _data[i] = value;
          });
        },
      );
      list.add(cb);
    }

    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: list
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for may be a `Key` property

Here is the [Key property document](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html)

[When to Use Keys (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc)